# Union of Joins vs. Join of unions

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to choose between what I think are two choices to get the same data.

I have one table that has the IDs of interest, and a set of 4 tables similar to each other that have data for those IDs.  Once I have the rows for each ID, I'll use them to get maximum status field, or the minimum date field, etc. (across the 4 tables).

I can see structuring this query as 1 join to a union of the 4 tables, or as a union of 4 joins.  Which is more efficient?  FWIW, I find the first easier to understand, and probably easier to maintain.

Spelling out the two choices:

Join idTable against a sub-select of the 4 tables UNIONed together:

```
select ss.id, ss.study, ss.status, ss.date
from ( -- subselect ss
        select tx.id, tx.study, tx.status, tx.date
      from table_tx tx
    UNION  
    select cfu.id, cfu.study, cfu.status, cfu.date
      from table_cfu cfu
    UNION  
    select sfu.id, sfu.study, sfu.status, sfu.date
      from table_sfu sfu
    UNION  
    select bsl.id, bsl.study, bsl.status, bsl.date
      from table_bsl bsl
  ) ss
inner join 
idTable id on id.id = ss.id AND id.study = ss.study
```

A union of idTable joined against each of the four:

```
select tx.id, tx.study, tx.status, tx.date
  from table_tx tx
  inner join 
  idTable id on id.id = tx.id AND id.study = tx.study
UNION  
select cfu.id, cfu.study, cfu.status, cfu.date
  from table_cfu cfu
  inner join 
  idTable id on id.id = cfu.id AND id.study = cfu.study
UNION  
select sfu.id, sfu.study, sfu.status, sfu.date
  from table_sfu sfu
  inner join 
  idTable id on id.id = sfu.id AND id.study = sfu.study
UNION  
select bsl.id, bsl.study, bsl.status, bsl.date
  from table_bsl bsl
  inner join 
  idTable id on id.id = bsl.id AND id.study = bsl.study
```

Or is there a better choice other than these?

Comment: I don't know anything about your application, but it seems like the data could be in a single table with an added column like "type" taking the place of the old table names.  Then you won't need the UNIONS at all.  The queries would become much simpler and easy to maintain (which is super important) and you'd probably even get a tiny performance boost.

Comment: In sql-server you can check the execution plan

Answer (score 0):

It's going to depend on what your data looks like in terms of the number of rows in each of the tables, so your best bet is going to be trying out both approaches and seeing if either is better.

If I assume, though, that each of your tables tx, cfu, sfu, and bsl contain a million rows, then I expect it would be faster to limit those 4 large sets to a single row before unioning them as opposed to creating a 4-million row set and then joining it.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server can transform the first to the second but not the reverse.

That said, there is no way to know which is better because it depends on a lot of things (row counts, filter selectivity, ...). The only sound answer is to look at the plan and/or test.